# What is the proper Java Config for simple file copy

Tags: spring-integration

I'm extremely new to Spring, and even more-so to Spring Integration, so apologies if this is a very basic question.

I'm wanting to build a very basic log file processor to learn the ropes. Very similar to this: [example](http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/integration/94764-file-channel-adapter-issues)

I'm also wanting to use a java config approach, and most of the examples I've been following are all XML driven and I'm having a hard time doing the translation.

Ultimately I'd like to recursively poll a source directory for log files and use a persistence store to keep track of what's been found.

Then, copy those files to be processed to a processing folder, and then kick off a spring batch job to process the contents of the file.

When everything completes the processed file can be deleted from the processing location.

I can't seem to figure out the proper way to wire up (using general java config of SpEL) the flow. Also, I'm still very unsure of what the proper pieces should be.

Again something along these basic, high-level lines for the file moving:

```
file:inbound-channel-adapter -> channel -> file:outbound-adapter
```

[basic sample](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/tree/master/basic/file)

Here is what I have so far

**EDIT**

I've updated with Artem's solution. My source files are now properly copied to the destination location. Thanks Artem!

Ultimately I am still facing the same problem. The files to be scanned are found immediately (and the metadata-store.properties files is populated immediately) but the files are slowly copied to the destination folder. If a crash happens, any source files that have not been copied to the destination folder will essentially be "lost". Perhaps I need to look at other forms of persistence stores, like a custom jdbcfilter.

```
@Value("${logProcessor.filenamePattern}")
private String filenamePattern;

@Value("${logProcessor.sourceDirectory}")
private String sourceDirectory;

@Value("${logProcessor.processingDirectory}")
private String processingDirectory;

@Bean
@InboundChannelAdapter(channel = "sourceFileChannel", poller = @Poller(fixedRate = "5000"))
public MessageSource<File> sourceFiles() {

        CompositeFileListFilter<File> filters = new CompositeFileListFilter<>();
        filters.addFilter(new SimplePatternFileListFilter(filenamePattern));
        filters.addFilter(persistentFilter());

        FileReadingMessageSource source = new FileReadingMessageSource();
        source.setAutoCreateDirectory(true);
        source.setDirectory(new File(sourceDirectory));
        source.setFilter(filters);
        source.setUseWatchService(true);

        return source;
    }

@Bean
@InboundChannelAdapter(channel = "processingFileChannel", poller = @Poller(fixedRate = "5000"))
    public MessageSource<File> processingFiles() {

        CompositeFileListFilter<File> filters = new CompositeFileListFilter<>();
        filters.addFilter(new SimplePatternFileListFilter(filenamePattern));

        FileReadingMessageSource source = new FileReadingMessageSource();
        source.setAutoCreateDirectory(true);
        source.setDirectory(new File(processingDirectory));
        source.setFilter(filters);

        return source;
    }

@Bean
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "sourceFileChannel")
public MessageHandler fileOutboundChannelAdapter() {
    FileWritingMessageHandler adapter = new FileWritingMessageHandler(new File(processingDirectory));
    adapter.setDeleteSourceFiles(false);
    adapter.setAutoCreateDirectory(true);
    adapter.setExpectReply(false);
    return adapter;
}


    @Bean
    public MessageChannel sourceFileChannel() {
        return new DirectChannel();
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageChannel processingFileChannel() {
        return new DirectChannel();
    }

    @Bean
    public DefaultDirectoryScanner defaultDirectoryScanner() {
        return new DefaultDirectoryScanner();
    }

    @Bean
    public FileSystemPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter persistentFilter() {
        FileSystemPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter fileSystemPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter = new FileSystemPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter(metadataStore(), "");
        fileSystemPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter.setFlushOnUpdate(true);
        return fileSystemPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter;
    }

    @Bean
    public PropertiesPersistingMetadataStore metadataStore(){
        PropertiesPersistingMetadataStore metadataStore = new PropertiesPersistingMetadataStore();
        metadataStore.setBaseDirectory("C:\\root\\code\\logProcessor");
        return metadataStore;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You config is good so far.

Having such a complex task, I'm not sure how to help you.

You should ask more specific question. We can't write the solution for you.

Not sure why you need to copy files from one dir to another, if you can simply poll them from the source dir, store in the `metadataStore` and start a file processing.

So, far I see a small problem in your config. The `FileWritingMessageHandler` sends results to the `processingFileChannel` and the same is done by the second `FileReadingMessageSource`. I'm not sure that it is your intention. Just in case to pay your attention.

You might also need to know about [`FileSplitter`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/files.html#file-splitter), which lets you to process file line by line.

Also you say `processingDirectory`, but then you use `tmpDir` for the `FileWritingMessageHandler`, which, I guess, assumes your copy logic.

Let's do the task step by step! And then you figure out what, where and how to use!

**EDIT**

If  you need just copy file to the `processingDirectory` without any reply, you should do one-way adapter:

```
@Bean
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "sourceFileChannel")
public MessageHandler fileOutboundChannelAdapter() {
    FileWritingMessageHandler adapter = new FileWritingMessageHandler(new File(processingDirectory));
    adapter.setDeleteSourceFiles(true);
    adapter.setAutoCreateDirectory(true);
    adapter.setExpectReply(false);
    return adapter;
}
```

And then that your `@InboundChannelAdapter(channel = "processingFileChannel"` is good to pick up files for processing.

Not sure that you need to `DeleteSourceFiles` though...

Comment: Thank you for your response Artem. The reason for the file copy is to avoid the problem where the files have been found, but have not been processed, similar to this [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25756387/prevent-duplicates-across-restarts-in-spring-integration) I will update my answer to be more specific, I'm just confused as to how to use an outbound adapter.

Comment: Thanks Artem, that works great. I agree, the source files can remain, thus adapter.setDeleteSourceFiles(false); I will mark this as the answer, thank you! I should open a new question because I'm still facing the same problem. The metadata-store.properties files lists all the found files immediately, but the files are copied to the destination folder slowly. Thus if a crash occurs there will still be files that are not processed. This is what I'm ultimately trying to solve.

Comment: Would a persistent queue be more appropriate to handle the scenario?

Comment: There is `maxMessagesPerPoll` option for the `@Poller` which is `1` for inbound channel adapter by default. Consider to switch it to `-1` to process all the available files at once.

Comment: Thanks Artem, changing `maxMessagesPerPoll` to -1 did indeed process all the files at once! In my test it worked great, I guess my only concern would be the performance for large files/filesets.

Comment: Well, just imagine how is fast to copy large files from one dir to another just using your file system directly. :-)

Comment: Good point Artem. Just trying to wrap my head around the process. I just don't want to miss files that need to be processed in case of a crash. Thanks again for all the help!