# How to change filename using a FileWritingMessageHandler

Tags: spring-integration

This is a follow-on to [my earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39496030/what-is-the-proper-java-config-for-simple-file-copy) about copying files using spring integration.

The basic flow is to recursively scan a directory for matching files. Once files are found a persistent metadata store is used to track the files and then a @ServiceActivator is used to copy the files to a /processing folder. A seperate @InboundChannelAdapter is used to scan this /processing folder to then kick off a spring batch job.

The problem I'm facing is that I'd like to rename the file as it's copied to the /processing folder, but any expression I use for the DefaultFilenameGenerator doesn't seem to work as the message headers simply have 'id' and 'timestamp', but I cannot reference either of them.

From the [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/files.html) the 2nd case of the default behavior appears to be executed:

> 1. Evaluate the expression against the Message and, if the result is a non-empty String, use it as the filename.
> 2. Otherwise, if the payload is a java.io.File, use the file’s filename.
> 3. Otherwise, use the Message ID appended with .msg as the filename.

Ultimately I'd like to use an expression like this:

```
headers['id'] + '_' + headers['file_name']
```

But anything I use is either ignored, or errors out. The code snippet below attempts to use headers['id'] but that results in an empty string (I'm guessing?) and thus the 2nd default behavior kicks in.

```
    @Bean
    @InboundChannelAdapter(channel = "sourceFileChannel", poller = @Poller(fixedRate = "5000", maxMessagesPerPoll = "-1"))
    public MessageSource<File> sourceFiles() {

        CompositeFileListFilter<File> filters = new CompositeFileListFilter<>();
        filters.addFilter(new SimplePatternFileListFilter(filenamePattern));
        filters.addFilter(persistentFilter());

        FileReadingMessageSource source = new FileReadingMessageSource();
        source.setAutoCreateDirectory(true);
        source.setDirectory(new File(sourceDirectory));
        source.setFilter(filters);
        source.setUseWatchService(true);

        return source;
    }

    @Bean
    @InboundChannelAdapter(channel = "processingFileChannel", poller = @Poller(fixedRate = "5000", maxMessagesPerPoll = "-1"))
    public MessageSource<File> processingFiles() {

        CompositeFileListFilter<File> filters = new CompositeFileListFilter<>();
        filters.addFilter(new SimplePatternFileListFilter(filenamePattern));
        filters.addFilter(new AcceptOnceFileListFilter<>());

        FileReadingMessageSource source = new FileReadingMessageSource();
        source.setAutoCreateDirectory(true);
        source.setDirectory(new File(processingDirectory));
        source.setFilter(filters);
        return source;
    }

    @Bean
    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "sourceFileChannel")
    public MessageHandler fileOutboundChannelAdapter() {
        FileWritingMessageHandler adapter = new FileWritingMessageHandler(new File(processingDirectory));
        adapter.setDeleteSourceFiles(false);
        adapter.setAutoCreateDirectory(true);
        adapter.setExpectReply(false);
        adapter.setFileNameGenerator(defaultFileNameGenerator());
        return adapter;
    }

    @Bean
    public DefaultFileNameGenerator defaultFileNameGenerator() {
        DefaultFileNameGenerator defaultFileNameGenerator = new DefaultFileNameGenerator();
        defaultFileNameGenerator.setHeaderName("id");
        //defaultFileNameGenerator.setExpression("headers['id']");
        return defaultFileNameGenerator;
    }
```

**EDIT**

The workaround I used was extending DefaultFileNameGenerator myself. However Artem properly showed in the comments how to access the pieces needed.

Here is Artem's proper solution:

```
defaultFileNameGenerator.setExpression("headers.id + '_' + payload.name");
```

Here was the workaround code:

```
public class FilenameGenerator extends DefaultFileNameGenerator {
    public FilenameGenerator() {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    public String generateFileName(Message<?> message) {
        return message.getHeaders().getId().toString() + "_" + ((File) message.getPayload()).getName();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `file_name` header after `FileReadingMessageSource`, so you have to use `payload`:

```
defaultFileNameGenerator.setExpression("headers.id + '_' + payload.name");
```

Comment: Thanks again Artem, that worked perfectly. I guess what was throwing me off was that I was trying `headers['id']` versus the correct format of what you showed `headers.id`. Thanks again!

Comment: No, `headers['id']` is fine too. Your problem was `null` for the `file_name`. The `headers['id']` is `MapAccessor` and it is null-safe. The shorter `headers.id` is `PropertyAccessor` which throws `NPE` if there is no such a `key` in `Map`. But `id` is always present in `MessageHeaders`! :-)

Comment: Ah, now I see. Thank you for the detailed explanations as always. I also tried `defaultFileNameGenerator.setExpression("headers['id']");` but this was ignored and the original filename was preserved, so I just didn't follow.